# Problemas con una función que retorna un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, poo

Creé un servicio donde tengo una array con objetos y realicé una función donde recorro todo el array y quiero que me retorne solo los objetos que el valor de la propiedad sea === a alquiler:
Función: [Contenido es el nombre del array de objectos], [nuevoarray es un array donde pretendo almacenar cada uno de los objetos]

```
 getalquiler() { this.contenido.forEach(obj => {
  if (obj.condicion === 'alquilar'){
    this.arraynuevo.push(resp);
  }return this.arraynuevo});}
```

¿Esta función me devuelve un error alguien me podría explicar porqué?

Comment: Aclaro: *que el valor de la propiedad 'condución' sea = a 'alquilar'

Comment: Pues si estás usando `forEach`, SIEMPRE vas a obtener `undefined`, que es lo único que devuelve `forEach` tal y como indica la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach#Valor_de_retorno) del método... Cómo pretendes que funcione un `return` dentro de un método QUE SE DEBE EJECUTAR PARA CADA OBJETO? Cual devolvería, el primero que encuentre? El segundo? El último? Para eso deberías usar `filter`, tal como te indica @AlbertoSiurob en su respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta específica

"**¿Esta función me devuelve un error alguien me podría explicar porqué?**"

Antes de nada, el código que aportas está incompleto ya que si copio y pego directamente en un archivo .js, éste falla por estructura.

Entiendo que al faltar la palabra reservada "function" y ver el `this`, hablamos de un método que has extraido de una clase/objeto y expuesto aquí. Como comentario para futuras ocasiones te recomiendo agregar tódo el código o realizar pseudocódigo lo mas fiel al problema para facilitar la respuesta, en este caso al ser algo simple no es mucho problema, de otra forma son "errores adicionales".

Si partimos de que el código debería ser algo similar a:

```
class my_service {
  contenido = [
    {id: 1, condicion: 'alquilar'},
    {id: 2, condicion: 'otra_cosa'},
    {id: 3, condicion: 'diferente_cosa'},
    {id: 4, condicion: 'alquilar'},
    {id: 5, condicion: 'alquilar'},
    {id: 6, condicion: 'algo_distinto'}
  ];

  getalquiler() {
    this.contenido.forEach(obj => {
      if (obj.condicion === 'alquilar'){
        return obj;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**DEBUG Y ANÁLISIS**

No existe ningún problema en cuanto a ejecución, es decir funciona correctamente, sin embargo no realiza lo que buscas concretamente.

Analicemos juntos el código y que es lo que está sucediendo.

**1.-** Acceso propiedad del objeto

Cuando situas `condicion`, entiendo que es el atributo de tus objetos en ese array de datos, es decir la propiedad de ese objeto que almacena la palabra que buscas 'alquilar', si no es así, entonces fíjate en el ejemplo, ya que estás accediendo a otra propiedad distinta.

**2.-** Hay datos de tipo 'alquilar' en tu base de datos

Por otra parte, si no existe ningún objeto que sea de `alquilar` entonces digamos que tu condición `if`, no va a encontrar nada.

**3.-** Si existen datos y los encontramos ¿A dónde van con el return?

Es decir, retornas pero el error está en el `foreach`, ya que no es una función que te permita retornar y almacenar como lo estás haciendo.

Para esta finalidad existen otras funciones específicas de JS y por esta razón tu función deolvería como mucho "undefined" como puedes observar en la ejecución ejemplo final.

Si sitúas un `return console.log(obj)` en tu función, podrás observar por consola está correcta, es decir encuentra y llega a mostrar el objeto encontrado / **filtrado** pero *no se retorna ni almacena "en ninguna parte"*.

Ahora, he mencionado algo interesante `filtrado`, quiero invitarte a investigar las funciones nativas de javascript que te ahorran tiempo, esfuerzo y "reinventar la rueda" por así decirlo.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Puedes ahorrarte usar `foreach` + `if` + `return` + `{}`, de la siguiente forma:

```
  getalquiler() {
    return this.contenido.filter((obj) => obj.condicion === 'alquilar');
  }
```

Traducido a lenguaje humano sería:
"Método `getalquiler` que retorna la "operación" de filtrado de tu array de objetos cuando el objeto cumpla la condición de 'alquilar'."

La operación que buscamos es `filter`, que significa directamente filtrar.
Resumiendo su funcionamiento, realiza un bucle sobre tu array de objetos (como un foreach), los cuales va retornando en la variable `obj` ("magia interna de JS"). Ahora la propia función filter retorna un array con aquellos objetos que cumplan la condición de filtrado directamente,tan solo debes igualar la operación a una nueva variable.

**ENRIQUECIMIENTO ADICIONAL**

Puedes leer mas en detalle:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter

Además, te sugiero mirar "map, find, findIndexOff, fill, some, every"

**FUNCIONAL COMPARATIVO**

Aquí presento el ejemplo funcional:

```js
class my_service {
  contenido = [
    {id: 1, condicion: 'alquilar'},
    {id: 2, condicion: 'otra_cosa'},
    {id: 3, condicion: 'diferente_cosa'},
    {id: 4, condicion: 'alquilar'},
    {id: 5, condicion: 'alquilar'},
    {id: 6, condicion: 'algo_distinto'}
  ];

  getalquiler_new() {
    return this.contenido.filter((obj) => obj.condicion === 'alquilar');
  }

  getalquiler_old() { 
    return this.contenido.forEach(obj => {
    if (obj.condicion === 'alquilar'){
      return obj;
    }});
  }
  
}


const servicio = new my_service();
console.log(servicio.getalquiler_new());
console.log(servicio.getalquiler_old());
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Sergio , estoy leyendo documentacion acerca del metodo filter() y lo comprendo. Pero sigo sin comprender porqué el Foreach : "No es una función que te permita retornar y almacenar como lo estás haciendo".

Comment: En el caso del `forEach( obj => ...)`, es literalmente `porCada`, simplemente, por cada valor y "fin". Podrías utilizar un forEach y dentro, donde tienes `return obj`, poner `nuevo_array.push(obj)` es decir, cuando encuentre la condición, "empuja" llena un nuevo array con los valores encontrados, pero en ningún caso por como está hecho `forEach` en si mismo, retorna nada. Es una forma abreviada de un `for`. El `for` en sí mismo tampoco retorna nada. Intuyo que por la repetición de este tipo de operacines, aparecieron métodos específicos que simplifican el código y aportan nuevas posibilidades

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la función [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) para hacer ese trabajo, te dejo un ejemplo

```js
 const contenido = [ 
   {
    id: 1,
    tipo: 'renta'
   },
   {
    id: 2,
    tipo: 'venta'
   },
   {
    id: 3,
    tipo: 'alquiler'
   },
   {
    id: 4,
    tipo: 'venta'
   },
   {
    id: 5,
    tipo: 'alquiler'
   }
   
];
 
 const getAlquiler = () => {
  return contenido.filter( o => o.tipo === 'alquiler' );
 }
 
 const result = getAlquiler();
 console.log( result );
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero, falta especificar qué tipo de error está retornando.

Por otro lado, infiero que el error ocurre al momento de no declarar un return por defecto. Para solucionar este error en concreto, debes declarar un `return` que se ejecute sí o sí de no resultar verdadera la validación `obj.condicion === 'alquilar'`. Así:

```js
getalquiler() {
  for (const objeto of this.contenido) { // Uso este for .. of sólo para mayor claridad
    if (objeto.condicion === 'alquilar') {
      return objeto;
    }
  }
  return undefined; // <- Esto sería un return por defecto
}
```

### Update:

Corrijo mi respuesta:

Debido a que lo esperado es retornar un array, puede usar `Array.filter()` (como está indicado en otra respuesta) o con `Array.reduce()`. Con este último, funcionaría así:

```js
getalquiler() {
  return this.contenido.reduce((filtrado, objeto) => {
    if (objeto.condicion === 'alquilar') {
      filtrado.push(objeto)
    }
    return filtrado;
  }, [])
}
```

Comment: Con esa función, al primer objeto que encuentre con la condición, saldrá de la función dada la instrucción de `return`. Debes almacenar los objetos en una variable temporal para terminar el ciclado y luego retornar esa variable.

Comment: SÏ, actualicé mi respuesta debido a que malentendí la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

la funcion forEach lo que hace es ejecutar una callback por cada elemento del array y su valor de retorno es undefinied. lo que pudieras hacer es encapsularlo en otra funcion que sea la que devuelva, pero ojo entonces forEach perderia el sentido, porque ya existe array.Map. Ejemplo

```
    function applyFilter(){
    
     var words = ['uno', 'dos', 'tres', 'cuatro'];

     words.forEach(function(word) {
     
       if (word === 'uno') {
         words.shift();
         //modificas el array o lo que quieras
       }
     });

     return words;
    }

   console.log(applyFilter());

   // ["dos", "tres", "cuatro"]
```

En dependencia de lo que quieras hacer será mejor la función **filter** o **map**
Ejemplo de uso de array.filter

```
var ages = [32, 33, 12, 40];

function checkAdult(age) {
    return age >= 18;
}

function myFunction() {
  console.log(ages.filter(checkAdult));
}
myFunction();

//[32, 33, 40]
```

Ejemplo de uso de array.map

```
var numeros = [1, 4, 9];
var dobles  = numeros.map(function(num) {
  return num * 2;
});

// dobles es ahora [2, 8, 18]
// numeros sigue siendo [1, 4, 9]
```

Espero haberte sido de ayuda
Saludos